# Netbeans 12.4 lombok not supported in Editor

Tags: java, netbeans, lombok

NetBeans 12.4. The editor does not see lombok annotations and considers them to be errors.

Maven project.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.12</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried different versions of lombok. I did not see any difference.

It was very upsetting after NB 8.2 (

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: https://projectlombok.org/setup/netbeans

Comment: Works for me with the latest lombok version (1.18.18). IIRC older versions where not working fine with Netbeans.

Comment: @Jens the info on that page is neither helpful nor necessary when using netbeans with maven projects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix the imports in your class.

Type ctrl+shift+I to include the lombok imports into your java class

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your IDE showing the class and the imports to your question? thx

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have found a solution.

I removed the plugin "The nb-javac Java editing support library". Menu Tools->Plugins. Then restart IDE and install this plugin again. Perhaps his version is more recent, I don't know. Restart IDE again. And now lombok works.

Magic. )

Answer (score 0):

Sometime there're problems with lombok releases and NetBeans which breaks the functionality. This happened quite some time in the past. So if you encounter any problems with lombok. You should

1. Try to upgrade lombok to the most recent lombok version.
2. Check the [bug tracker](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues?q=is%3Aissue+netbeans) for known issues. Normally they pop up quite fast.
3. Try to downgrade several versions.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

- Downloaded the `lombok.jar` to an arbitrary folder
- Under Tools/Libraries, I created a New Library, and added the downloaded jar file to the Library Classpath

It worked for a while, but suddenly stopped. Then I did the following:

- Removed the jar from the Library Classpath
- Restarted the IDE
- Re-added the jar file to the Library Classpath
- Restarted the IDE again

This prodecure resolved the issue. In my installation I didn't find the `nb-javac Java editing support library` plugin nor the project-specific Libraries settings, that's why I used the global Library setting.